# What advice would you give about having to move out during the last month of the lease on short notice?

Tags: real-estate-leasing

I am in the last month of my lease and already paid for this month. However, personal events have made it impossible to sign a new lease so I need to move out. Will my landlord keep my deposit?

Comment: Location is very important to these types of questions. Country and state.

Comment: Seems like you have fulfilled your lease, or did I misunderstand?  You paid all the months of the lease, the lease is over, you should get your deposit back?

Comment: You have paid for the final month. I believe that is all that matters to your landlord. As long as you are not asking for a pro-rated refund then you will have zero issues getting your deposit back. The only stipulation which I can imagine is that they won't give you the deposit until the paid-for month has ended because you can technically still live there even though you are moving out before the end.

Answer (score 5):

You need to consult the lease. That is your contract with the landlord that stipulates exactly how the end of lease works. If it is not spelled out in the lease you will need to look at your local tenant laws, which will likely address any gray areas.

Be careful it may auto-convert to a month-month lease if you don't give timely notice.